# Using package todonotes and auto-pst-pdf does not work

Tags: todonotes, auto-pst-pdf, chemnum

I need auto-pst-pdf so the package chemnum automatically number the chemicals I use in figueres. But I run into the problem that if I use the package todonotes at the same time my TexShop stops working.

So I use this example.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[
a4paper,                       %% DIN A4-Papier
DIV=calc,                       %% Satzspiegel berechnen
11pt,                          %% Schriftgröße
captions=tableheading,         %% Tabellenüber- statt unterschriften
english
]{scrreprt}                    %% KOMA-Skript Report als Klasse

\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption]{todonotes}       %%ToDo-Notes. 
\usepackage{chemnum}              %% Numbering chemical compounds
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}         %% needed for replacing temporary strings to numbers

\begin{document}
\listoftodos

Bla blub
\todo{Deckblatt designen}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:1}
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:2}
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:3}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{ChemDraw/CHI-014-CD15.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If I either comment out all todonotes or auto-pst-pdf everything works fine (except that I have no todo notes or my temporary strings don't get replaced of course)

After this output the TexShop stops working.
[image: After this output TexShop stops working]

[This is the complete .log fiile](https://www.sendspace.com/file/pmu55p)

Can anybody present me a solution for this problem?

Comment: If you get an error please always show the exact error from the log. I ran your example with `pdflatex --shell-escape` (but using `example-image` as the image) and it ran with no errors although of course none of the replacements matches in that case.

Comment: It is best to show the log as tex (in a code section) rather than as an image, but the image that you show shows no error (the pdf special warning is just a feature of auto-pst-pdf)

Comment: That's what I was wondering about too. I don't get an error, TexShop just crashes...
Maybe the problem lies with TexShop and not the used packages? The created PDF File makes Preview Stop working after some time and I can't open up my .tex file with TexShop until I delete the .pdf file beforehand

Comment: how can the editor crash just running tex, that's odd,  what happens if you just run `pdflatex --shell-escape your file` on the commandline?

Comment: Using the command line like you suggested works fine. Still Preview crashes after 20 seconds or so, so something's still not working alright.

Comment: so it's probably something in the pdf generated from your specific eps file that is killing your pdf viewer (does it work with xpdf or your browser or any other pdf viewer you have to hand?) It's probably not possible to debug without that eps file (unless you can make it fail replacing the text example-a in the image `example-image-a` and re-post the example. Your log image shows `test-pics.pdf` being included is that generated from the code as posted?

Comment: [this](https://www.sendspace.com/file/duaacf) is the .eps file I'm using. Yes test-pics.pdf is generated correctly.
To be honest I didn't get what you meant with this example-image-a.

Comment: Adobe Acrobat and my Browser did not crash while displaying the generated .pdf

Comment: You are using texlive 2015. At that time there has been some reports about incompabilities between preview (used by auto-pst-pdf) and pgf (used by todonotes). E.g. https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/315/. I don't know if all issues have been resolved, as I if possible avoid auto-pst-pdf but you could try to update to texlive 2017 (normally it can be installed parallel to an existing texlive but as I'm on windows I don't know the details for your OS).

Comment: Sadly i can't avoid auto-pst-pdf since I need it so the temporary strings in my .eps files can be replaced. I'm using Mac OS 10.12.5 and use MacTex from [tug.org](http://tug.org/mactex/). I installed the newest version of MacTex, but the problem continued.

Comment: My solution right now is switching to the package [easy-todo](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/easy-todo). Not as pretty as todonotes, but it's working and those todo notes won't be visible in the final document anyways.

Thank you all for your help so far.